# Collections sorting

Tags: apex

I have a Trigger on Object Group__c. Group__C had many to one relationship with Account.
Groups have following fields..

Status__c(Active and inactive are values),Effective_date__c and others. Now i want to filter groups on the following criteria..

> 1. Active vs multiple Inactive...Active will wins..
> 2. Multiple Active vs Multiple Active ...latest Effective_date__c will win
> 3. Inactive vs Inactive.. latest Effective_date__c will win
> 4. Multiple Active and Multiple Inactive then always active win with latest effective date.

Now at run time I will have,  List of list of groups

I have implemented follwoing so that i can pick every  group at zero location of Lists.

That would be the group whose fields i will use to roll up to account

```
global class GroupWrapper implements Comparable {
    public Group__c grp=null;

    //constructor

    public GroupWrapper(Group__c grp){
        this.grp=grp;
    }

    global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo){
        //cast argument to GroupWrapper 

        GroupWrapper compareToGrp=(GroupWrapper)compareTo;
        Integer returnValue=0;
        if ( grp.Initial_Effective_Date__c> compareToGrp.grp.Initial_Effective_Date__c) {

            returnValue = 1;
        } else if (grp.Initial_Effective_Date__c<compareToGrp.grp.Initial_Effective_Date__c) {
            // Set return value to a negative value.
            returnValue = -1;
        }

        return returnValue;

    }



}
```

Right now it is just filtering my list on the basic of Initial_Effective_Date__c..can i do status filtering also...

Or any other best approach to acheive the same.

Comment: Can you explain how `Status` indicates `Active`/`Inactive`? Are there multiple statuses for each or is it more straightforward?

Comment: Thanks Adrian..its just Picklist having values Status and Inactive

Comment: So any status that is not `Inactive` is `Active`? Or is one of two picklist values `Status`? Still needs clarification.

Comment: Yes active and inactive are just two picklist value for  field status__C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your `compareTo` method as follows:

```
global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo)
{
    GroupWrapper that = (GroupWrapper)compareTo;
    if (this.grp.Status__c == 'Active')
        return (that.grp.Status__c == 'Inactive') ? -1 : compareDates(that);
    if (this.grp.Status__c == 'Inactive')
        return (that.grp.Status__c == 'Active') ? 1 : compareDates(that);
    return 0;
}
Integer compareDates(GroupWrapper that)
{
    if (this.getDate() == that.getDate()) return 0;
    return (this.getDate() > that.getDate()) ? 1 : -1;
}
Date getDate() { return grp.Initial_Effective_Date__c; }
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian..let me try with this one..I will let you know the results..

Comment: You'll need to add some null checking if any of these fields are not required, but you haven't really laid that out in your OP.

Comment: Thanks Adrian...For Null checking, we will always have those values comming in group. Will this code filter groups on the basis of above four conditions ....like when we will pass list<group__C>...at list[0] will have group which will satisfy our four conditions...Please Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yeah it should satisfy all four as per my understanding. You'll have to write some tests (or functionally test) to verify.

Comment: Thanks...i am implementing the same and will do testing and let you know the results..That was so quick help. I really appreciate that. Thanks a lot

Comment: return (that.grp.Status__c = 'Inactive') ? -1 : compareDates(that);...this line is throwing error First argument of ternary must be Boolean: String

Comment: Need to use double equals for comparison. Oops.

Comment: All set but while saving it is giving duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>..not showing error line

Comment: That error cannot possibly be related to this code...

Comment: This is weird error, i have not seen before...its not showing any line number for error.but throwing error...

Comment: I have resolved it..actually one more global method was defined in org with same name...i dont know how, but changing the name of method, error gone.

Comment: It has working as expected..Almost 90 percent i have done testing.. You are great..thanks..... I am doing testing for all the possible combinations....Once testing complete i will let you know.

Comment: Just so you know, you can vote up to show you appreciate the effort.